# Matplotlib axvspan() function fills wrong date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-datareader

When I want to use axvspan to fill the dates, It fills wrong area.  I think it reversed axvspans. The reason for the problem may be the dataframe that I imported from World Bank.  How can I fix it? Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import wb
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime (2000,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime (2021,5,1)
ind = ['FM.LBL.BMNY.ZG',
       'FR.INR.DPST'
       ]
df = wb.download(indicator=ind, country='CHN', start=start, end=end).dropna();df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Country',
              'Year',
              'Broad money growth (annual %) - China',
              'Deposit interest rate (%)'
              ]
df=df.sort_values(by='Year', ascending=True)
axes= df.plot(x='Year',subplots=True, figsize=(20,12), layout=(1,2), colormap='summer', legend=True)

for ax, col in zip(axes.flatten(), df.columns):
    ax.axvspan('2007-1-12', '2009-6-1', color='teal', alpha=0.5,
               label='2008 Crisis')
    ax.axvspan('2019-12-1', '2020-2-1', color='orange', alpha=0.5,
               label='Pandemic')
    ax.set_title(col)

axes[0,0].set_title('Broad money growth (annual %) - China')
axes[0,0].invert_xaxis()
axes[0,0].legend(loc='upper left')
axes[0,0].set_ylabel('Percent(Annual)')
axes[0,0].invert_xaxis()

axes[0,1].set_title('Deposit interest rate (%)')
axes[0,1].invert_xaxis()
axes[0,1].legend(loc='upper left')
axes[0,1].set_ylabel('Percent(Annual)')
axes[0,1].invert_xaxis()



plt.suptitle("Financial Sector in China",fontweight="bold")
plt.show()
```

[image: you can see it didn't fill 2019, fills another dates.]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Correcting xaxis dtype in pandas.plot to correct vspan locations

The year column in df is an object not an int, so the xlim is (-1, 21) and the labels are formatted on top of those index locations. Therefore, when you go to place your vspan, the x location entered does not match those of the x axis. To fix this, simply make your year column an int and make your vspan in terms of years as ints.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import wb
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

start = datetime.datetime (2000,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime (2021,5,1)
ind = ['FM.LBL.BMNY.ZG',
       'FR.INR.DPST'
       ]
df = wb.download(indicator=ind, country='CHN', start=start, end=end).dropna();df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Country',
              'Year',
              'Broad money growth (annual %) - China',
              'Deposit interest rate (%)'
              ]
df=df.sort_values(by='Year', ascending=True)
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(int)

axes= df.plot(x='Year',subplots=True, figsize=(15,5), layout=(1,2), colormap='summer', legend=True)

for ax, col in zip(axes.flatten(), df.columns):
    ax.axvspan(2007, 2009, color='teal', alpha=0.5, label='2008 Crisis')
    ax.axvspan(2019, 2020, color='orange', alpha=0.5, label='Pandemic')
    ax.set_title(col)
    ax.set_xlim(2000, 2021)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2))

axes[0,0].set_title('Broad money growth (annual %) - China')
axes[0,0].legend(loc='upper left')
axes[0,0].set_ylabel('Percent(Annual)')


axes[0,1].set_title('Deposit interest rate (%)')
axes[0,1].legend(loc='upper left')
axes[0,1].set_ylabel('Percent(Annual)')

plt.suptitle("Financial Sector in China",fontweight="bold")
```

Comment: thank you very much, you caught an amazing point. But I have a question for you. I understood the first part of your answer that is transforming 'year' column. But, what is the function of 'ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2))' ? I didn't understand why you used 'ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2))'?

Comment: That was just to make the x-axis look nice for you. Formatters and locators determine the tick labels. They are a very useful tool to be familiar with. https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html

Comment: thank you. I have faced a problem just now. I just copied your useful codes to another plot which has 9 subplots, but it just only shows the data after 2014., the data before 2014 is blank. what should I do :( I have added just now the plot the question. can you look at it :(

Comment: I'm not sure, you would have to look at the data your are plotting and your axis limits.

Comment: If you would like to look at it, I can edit the codes on the question .